# Formstone asap.js proper usage in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to use an asap.js (docs: http://formstone.it/components/asap/) component on my wordpress site. This plugin is provided with formstone set of useful scripts. However I can't figure out how to properly address my wordpress content using this script.

I tried this code but it doesn;t seem to work nor I have any errors in chrome's console. Can anyone provide me a simple example, something I can start with?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var $content,
    $deferred;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind ASAP events
    $(window).on("request.asap", pageRequested)
        .on("progress.asap", pageLoadProgress)
        .on("load.asap", pageLoaded)
        .on("render.asap", pageRendered)
        .on("error.asap", pageLoadError);

    $content = $(".myPageWrapper");

    // Init ASAP
    $.asap({
        cache: false,
        selector: "a:not(.no-asap)",
        transitionOut: function() {
            if ($deferred) {
                $deferred.reject();
            }

            $deferred = $.Deferred();

            $content.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, function() {
                console.log("Animate complete");

                $deferred.resolve();
            });

            return $deferred;
        }
    });

    // Remember to init first page
    pageRendered();
});

function pageRequested(e) {
    // update state to reflect loading
    console.log("Request new page");
}

function pageLoadProgress(e, percent) {
    // update progress to reflect loading
    console.log("New page load progress", percent);
}

function pageLoaded(e) {
    // unbind old events and remove plugins
    console.log("Destroy old page");
}

function pageRendered(e) {
    // bind new events and initialize plugins
    console.log("Render new page");

    $content.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
}

function pageLoadError(e, error) {
    // watch for load errors
    console.warn("Error loading page: ", error);
}



});
```

The class="myPageWrapper" is used in my wordpress theme file **content-page.php**:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="myPageWrapper">
  <?php the_content(); ?>
 </article>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a json object containing only the content to be replaced when making an ASAP request. I think something like this will work in WordPress, although there is probably a better way to hook into core filters:

```
<?php 

$isASAP = (isset($_GET["fs-asap"]) && $_GET["fs-asap"] == "true");
ob_start();

if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post(); 

        if (!$isASAP) :
?>
<article class="myPageWrapper">
<?php
        endif;

        the_content(); 

        if (!$isASAP) :
?>
</article>
<?php
        endif;
    endwhile; 
endif; 

if ($isASAP) :
    // If ASAP request, return json object with page pieces
    $page_content = ob_get_clean();

    $asap_content = json_encode(array(
        ".myPageWrapper" => $page_content
    ));

    header("Content-length: " . strlen($asap_content));
    die($asap_content);
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for such quick response! I did as you said, it's late so I didn't try to improve anything, will try in coming days.

First of all I think page loads much faster, but I am not so sure if everything works properly.

When I add the following: 

    $.asap("load", "http://dev.dermiclab.pl/decleor/");
to my site private.js file an infinite loop happens, without it just loads, without the eye candy animation. Would you be so kind and take a look? In my functions.php file I did ad asap.js after core.js

Comment: With this line of code:  $.asap("load", "dev.dermiclab.pl/decleor/"); and preserved log on chrome's console I didn't manage to catch any errors, it refreshing infinitely, without, as i wrote earlier it works without animation

Comment: When is the load function called? If it is being called on every page load, it will probably create a loop.

Comment: Okey, I understand you, the line is called in my private.js, so it is executed everytime page loades. Should I put it in header.php file?

Comment: I think it's workin now, can you confirm? http://dev.dermiclab.pl/decleor/ pass: dermiclab, how can I enable animation for this?

Comment: I don't think it is working. You still need to initialize ASAP. In your document ready callback you need something like:

    $.asap({
     selector: "a:not(.no-asap)"
    });

This will tell the plugin to watch all links, except those with a 'no-asap' class. Check out the demo code for animation implementation using promises: http://formstone.it/site/extra/asap/